# 1.9.1 cant seem to remove fax

Tags: onepage-checkout, ce-1.9.1.0

my layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">    
    <checkout_onepage_index>
        <reference name="checkout.onepage.billing">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>checkout/onepage/billing.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="checkout.onepage.shipping">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>
</layout>
```

And I have deleted the FAX line in both the billing and shipping.phtml, cleared cash, flushed, tried almost everything I can think of, even commented out the Fax in the billing in the base folder - the fax field still stays there, obviously I am doing something wrong and would apppreciate if anyone has an idea.

Comment: Are you sure those files are the ones used? Maybe there's a module overwriting those templates. Have you checked the template path hints?

Comment: You know, that's the problem with relying on self information - I "knew" I had the correct path. Turned on hints and sure enough, there's a persistent folder  inside RWD, with the billing.phtml 

..... overlooking the small stuff because I thought 'I knew'. I should have know better. 

Alex, thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is: there's a persistent folder inside the RWD theme that overides the edits made to the layout.xml

To make the change, I had to edit the layout.xml inside the persistent folder within RWD

Comment: -1 for vagueness. In fact I'm going to go out on a limb and say that's not what you did. There is no "layout.xml inside the persistent folder". In fact if I'm not mistaken there's no "layout.xml" anywhere in a typical Magento installation! I suspect you mean you edited persistent.xml inside the layout folder (i.e. rwd/default/layout/persistent.xml) and told it to use checkout/onepage/billing.phtml? You could have, as an alternative, removed the relevant bit of HTML from rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.html, which is probably safer...

Comment: As I wasn't using the RWD theme, the layout.xml had to be added to the RWD theme to stop the RWD persistent from taking over the process. So I added layout.xml to the rwd/default/layout folder.

Better practice to use layout.xml rather than editing core files.

Answer (score 0):

TO REMOVE COMPANY, FAX FIELD FROM MAGENTO ONEPAGE CHECKOUT 1.9
REMINDER: COMPANY FIELD AND FAX FIELD ETC. MOST BE REMOVED FROM GUEST AND REGISTERED CUSTOMER AND IN BILLING AND SHIPPING (IF YOU WISH TO REMOVE)

1. FOR REMOVING COMPANY, FAX ETC FIELD IN BILLING INFORMATION: OPEN app/design/frontend/rwd/template/persistant/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

FIND THE LINE:

AND REPLACE IT WITH THIS:

COMPANY FIELD SHOULD BE GONE STAY IN THIS FILE AND CHANGE FAX FIELD THE SAME IF YOU WISH.

NOW FOR SHIPPING GO TO: 
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml

1. AGAIN DO THE SAME TO REMOVE COMPANY, FAX FIELD ETC IN SHIPPING: LOOK FOR THE FILE: 
    (REMEMBER THIS FILE NAME IS LOCATED ABOVE THE FIELD NAME YOU WISH TO REMOVE, DO THE SAME AS THE FIRST LESSON:

DB
THANKS